# Azure Event Hub Offset

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I have implemented the code from the below link for receiving events from the event hub. But say there are 10 events and checkpoint is done for every 5 events. Now the program exits abnormally when reading the 7th event and if i restart the event processor host again then events (1,2,3,4,6) are re-read. Please suggest how will I again avoid re-read and read from the 7th event? Any example would be appreciated. Thanks.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/Java/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventhubs/samples/Basic/EventProcessorSample.java

Answer (score 3):

Well, in the context of the event hub it is your job to handle possible message duplication as the event hub guarantees at least once delivery, see

[Does Azure Event Hub guarantees at least once delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220685/does-azure-event-hub-guarantees-at-least-once-delivery)

We do not know your scenario so we cannot suggest something other than for you to build a duplicate message detection mechanism. For example, adding a unique id to the data prior to sending it to the event hub and have the processor check that against a list of processed messages.